# mysql - creating a "suggested artist to follow" query

Tags: mysql

I need to create a query that suggests artists to users depending on what they like and what other people who like what they like like. Hope you get that.

Anyhow, the tables in question are members (self explanatory) and artist_follows (which members follow who). I will add this query into a bigger query later on that will also get the artist info from the artists table for that ID.

Here's what I have so far, i've used `2` as the mock ID for the member.

```
SELECT 

M.ID AS M_ID,

F.ID AS F_ID,
F.follows_ID

FROM members M

LEFT JOIN artist_follows F 
ON F.ID = M.ID

WHERE M.ID ='2'
```

I realise its not very much at all but its as far as I can get hence why I came here.

Heres a breakdown of what needs to be done:

**1:**  Get ID from members table.

**2:**   Get follows_ID (who the user follows) from artist_follows by using the members ID

**3:**  Get IDS of  people who follow who the member follows. (call this "other members IDS" for the purpose of the next point).

**4:**  Get other artists IDS from "other members IDS" making sure artists that are already followed by the member aren't selected.

Hope breaking it down like that has helped!

**UPDATE!**
Lets have some mock data as suggested then. Lets say the member `2` follows artists with IDS `3` . Another member (`4`) follows `3` as well as `20`. The outcome of the query should therefore be `20`

**Schema:**

artist_follows;

```
CREATE TABLE `artist_follows` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `follows_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fav_ID` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fav_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `artists` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `members` (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

members;

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
 `ID` int(111) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `FNAME` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `SURNAME` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

Comment: Can you please post the two tables' structures and some sample data and what is the desired results from this sample data?

Comment: Is F.ID the ID of the member and F.follows_ID the ID of the artist?

Comment: @DavidGrenier yes thats right

Comment: @MahmoudGamal mock data added will add structures soon, but my servers being a pain. Don't think its too much of a requirement at the moment

Comment: @MahmoudGamal ive added the table structures

Comment: NetFlix pays a lot of money for this kind of query as it would pertain to movies.

Comment: @invertedSpear Really? Do they not already have one?

Comment: Perhaps past-tense would have been better. They ran contests with big money prizes to improve it. My point is that to get good recommendation query like what you want is a costly, difficult endeavor, and that asking for help on SO is unlikely to result in others producing this code for you out of general kindness. You might have better luck trying to apply an existing open-source recommendation engine like http://easyrec.org/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't realise it is such a complex query to do such a thing as so many sites use this kind of feature. Cheers for the link will take a look

Comment: @nbs189 It might not be necesarily difficult to write the query, but it certainly is to design the algorithm to produce the better recomendations.

Comment: @fronzenkoi that is true but the algrotithm I will be using Is straight forward, for the moment. It will just show other artists that are liked by people who like what you like

Comment: @nbs189 you're right. I didn't realize that you had a concrete thing in mind in your question. sorry for jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT new.follows_ID
FROM artist_follows fan
INNER JOIN artist_follows other ON other.follows_ID = fan.follows_ID
INNER JOIN artist_follows new ON new.ID = other.ID
WHERE new.follows_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT follows_ID FROM artist_follows WHERE ID = fan.ID )
AND fan.ID = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f523/1)

```
create table `members` (
    `id` int(111) not null auto_increment,
    primary key (`id`)
);
create table `artist_follows` (
    `id` int(11) not null,
    `follows_id` int(11) not null,
     constraint `id` foreign key (`id`) references `members` (`id`)
);
insert into members (id) values (2), (4);
insert into artist_follows (id, follows_id) values
(2, 3),
(4, 3),
(4, 20);
```

---

```
select distinct f3.follows_id follows
from
    members m
    inner join
    artist_follows f1 on f1.id = m.id
    inner join
    artist_follows f2 on f1.follows_id = f2.follows_id
    inner join
    artist_follows f3 on f2.id = f3.id 
where
    m.id = '2'
    and
    f3.follows_id not in (
        select follows_id
        from artist_follows
        where id = f1.id
    )
```

Comment: What is returned if 'member' and 'other' follow the same two artists?

Comment: Check the SQLFiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58f9/1/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58f9/1/0)

Comment: Which is then equal to my version.  :-)

Comment: @TerjeD. I didn't understand. You mean the result is still wrong?

Comment: No. Now they both work according to the specification. I just pointed out that the update made your query equal to my original suggestion